# Why is substitution applied outside the selected region?

Tags: visual-mode, substitute

Consider this string:

```
1 1 1
```

When I mark the first two 1s in visual mode and then `:'<,'>s/1/2/g`, all 1s on the line are replaced by 2s, not just those in the selected region.  Why is this the case and how can I restrict the operation to the selected text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:s[ubstitue]` command operates on whole lines and the `[range]` prefix is a range of lines.

To restrict the operation to just the visually-selected region, you can use the `\%V` atom in your search pattern. That is, visually-select the first two 1s in your example, then use this command to replace just those 1s:

```
'<,'>s/\%V1/2/g
```

See also

```
:help /\%V
```

The `:help` entry says to put `\%V` at the start and end of the pattern, but I didn't read that before trying it and it worked in the example here with `\%V` at just the start of the pattern.

Comment: Many thanks, @garyjohn.  I'm actually using Evil not Vim and found out that the \%V atom is not supported there.  Bummer.  For those who are interested, the relevant feature request is [here](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/610/v-atom-for-restricting-search-and-replace).

Answer (score 3):

That is, because you have provided only a line-based range for the `:s` command. There is no way to have an ex command apply to only a column-based selection. Specifically for the `:s` command there exists the `\%V` regex atom, that allows to substitute within a selection only.